# MySQL query with multiple conditions on same column

Tags: mysql, sql

`

```
Select peo.employee_number,
 bpf.name plan_name,
 typ.name plan_type,
 ben.effective_start_date,
 ben.effective_end_date,
 ben.enrt_cvg_strt_dt,
 ben.enrt_cvg_thru_dt
 from apps.ben_prtt_enrt_rslt_f   ben,
 apps.ben_pl_f               bpf,
 apps.ben_pl_typ_f           typ,
 apps.per_all_people_f       peo
 where (ben.enrt_cvg_thru_dt >= '01-JAN-2017' and typ.name ='Choice Health')
 and (ben.enrt_cvg_strt_dt >= ben.enrt_cvg_thru_dt and typ.name ='Waive 
 Health') 
 and ben.person_Id = peo.person_id
 and ben.pl_id = bpf.pl_id
 and typ.name ='choice Health' or 'waive health'
 and typ.pl_typ_id = ben.pl_typ_id`
```

I need to retrieve all the `employees` which are having `coverage_thru_date >= 01-JAN-2017` and enrolled for `plan_name ='Choice Health'` as well as those whose `coverage_start_dt >= coverage_thru_dt` and are enrolled for `plan_name='Waive Health'`

Comment: "I need to ..." - ok, Great!

Comment: Perhaps they're in the staff canteen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees 
WHERE (coverage_thru_date >= TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017')
      AND plan_name ='Choice Health')
      OR
      (coverage_start_dt >= coverage_thru_dt
       AND plan_name='Waive Medical');

--------------REVISED BASED ON SUPPLIED QUERY--------------
SELECT peo.employee_number, 
       bpf.name plan_name, 
       typ.name plan_type, 
       ben.effective_start_date, 
       ben.effective_end_date, 
       ben.enrt_cvg_strt_dt, 
       ben.enrt_cvg_thru_dt 
FROM   apps.ben_prtt_enrt_rslt_f ben, 
       apps.ben_pl_f bpf, 
       apps.ben_pl_typ_f typ, 
       apps.per_all_people_f peo 
WHERE    ( ben.enrt_cvg_thru_dt >= '01-JAN-2017' 
          AND typ.name = 'Choice Health' ) 
       OR 
         ( ben.enrt_cvg_strt_dt >= ben.enrt_cvg_thru_dt 
          AND typ.name = 'Waive Health' ) 
       AND ben.person_id = peo.person_id 
       AND ben.pl_id = bpf.pl_id 
       AND typ.pl_typ_id = ben.pl_typ_id;
```

Comment: Though, if you're defining the date, why convert it at run time? Why not use the database format to begin with?

Comment: @kchason valid point, I suppose he could use this condition `coverage_thru_date >= '2017-01-01'`

Comment: I need both the conditions to be satisfied. There are multiple entries for the same employee. I need all the record if the employee satisfies both conditions

Comment: This will satisfy both conditions, the `OR` will allow rows that meet either of the sets of conditions to be output.